# Truncate html text while taking in consideration "full stops" (in CachePHP TextHelper->truncate)

Tags: php, arrays, string, cakephp, truncate

**Edit:**

I ended up using CakePHP's **[`truncate()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0/lib/Cake/View/Helper/TextHelper.php#L197)** function. It's much faster and supports unicode :D

But the question still remains:

How can I make the function auto-detect full stops (`.`) and cut it just after that? So basically `$length` would be semi-ignored. So if the new text would have a incomplete sentence, more words would appended until the sentence finishes (Or removed, depending on the length of the string from the cut-off until next/previous sentence)

**Edit 2:**
I found out how to detect full stops. I replaced:

```
 if (!$exact) {
   $spacepos = mb_strrpos($truncate, ' ');

 ...
```

with

```
 if (!$exact) {
    $spacepos = mb_strrpos($truncate, '.');
 ...
```

**edit - problem:**

When I have tags like `img` that have dots inside their attributes, the text gets cutoff inside the tag:

```
 $text = '<p>Abc def abc def abc def abc def. Abc def <img src="test.jpg" /></p><p>abc def abc def abc def abc def.</p>';

 echo htmlentities(truncate($text));
```

How can I fix that? I'll open a bounty because the original question was already answered...

Comment: i think you just answered to your question. So you can continue and add new words until you find the "." and also substract words from computed text until you find "." Then compare the lengths and select the good one. After you do this, try to optimize :)

Comment: Hey! I think I did answer your original question, but I'm glad you found a solution! I was looking at the source code of Rails' `truncate` method, which offers very similar functionality to what you were looking for.

Comment: thanks Alex, can you post a link to the Rails function?

Comment: Of course, you can find it in [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate). You can pass a `:separator` parameter (which you could set to a period) which truncates the text at a natural break.

Comment: In honesty, the secondary problem should probably be another question altogether. But, since you've already put a bounty here we might as well take a crack at it :)

Comment: What is the situation that is causing your need to remove these full stops? Why are they appearing in the first place? What is your trouble with them? I feel there's a bigger problem that can be solved here, the current solution you're asking for seems like a hack for something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This snippet](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?402991-Truncate-string-to-last-full-stop&p=2908011&viewfull=1#post2908011) solves what you're looking for, and lists it's failures (full stops may not indicate sentence ends, and other punctuation can end sentences).

It will scan characters up to `$maxLen` and then effectively 'throw away' a partial sentence after the last full stop it finds.

In your case, you'd use this function just before you return `$new_text`.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve the "full-stop in tag" issue, you can use something similar to the following to detect if the stop is within a tag:

```
$str_len       = strlen($summary);
$pos_stop      = strrpos($summary, '.');
$pos_tag_open  = strrpos($summary, '<', -($str_len - $pos_stop));
$pos_tag_close = strpos($summary, '>', $pos_tag_open);

if (($pos_tag_open < $pos_stop) && ($pos_stop < $pos_tag_close)) {
  // Inside tag! Search for the next nearest prior full-stop.
  $pos_stop = strrpos($summary, '.', -($str_len - $pos_tag_open));
}

echo htmlentities(substr($summary, 0, $pos_stop + 1));
```

Obviously, this code can be optimized (and pulled out into its own function), but you get the idea. I have a feeling there is a regex that might handle this a bit more efficiently.

**Edit:**

Indeed, there *is* a regex that can do this, using negative lookahead:

```
$text = '<p>Abc def abc def abc def abc def. Abc def <img src="test.jpg" />abc</p>';

$count = preg_match_all("/\.(?!([^<]+)?>)/", $text, $arr, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$offset = $arr[0][$count-1][1];

echo substr($text, 0, $offset + 1)."\n";
```

This should be relatively efficient, at least in comparison with `truncate()` which also uses preg_match internally.

Comment: The regular expression above might work. But, considering the efficiency, in this case, we might truncate the string to a max_length first, and then do the preg to the truncated string. And yes, considerations must be done to the punctuation symbols.

Comment: @acpmasquerade - The intent is that the regex is run *after* the `truncate()` in order to find the earliest possible end-of-sentence before the maximum character limit. Using the regex beforehand is pointless as the result would just be lost when truncating the string to length.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression above [Truncate html text while taking in consideration "full stops" (in CachePHP TextHelper->truncate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438258/truncate-html-text-while-taking-in-consideration-full-stops-in-cachephp-texthe/7491744#7491744) might work.

But, considering the efficiency, in this case, we might truncate the string to a **max_length** first, and then do the **preg** to the truncated string. And yes, considerations must be done to the punctuation symbols.

Some more rules will create a proper logic to determine the ending of a sentence.

1. a space or a EOL after the punctuation symbol
2. First word after the picked punctuation, having an Upper case.
3. Multiple new lines (end of paragraph) after the punctuation symbol, etc.